# how to extract a submatrix from a bigger matrix in fortran?

Tags: matrix, fortran

Now, I have a `N*N` matrix, mat. I also have

`maskmat=(a(1),a(2),...,a(i),...a(N))`.

`a(i)` equals `0` or `1`.

If `a(i)==1`, the i-th colomn and i-th row of the matrix mat should be removed. If `a(i)==0`, we don't make any changes. Thus, we can get a submatrix accoring to the rule `maskmat`.

How to achieve it in Fortran?

Comment: I think a combination of `pack` and `unpack` could do it, with appropriate masks.

Comment: Have you tried something? Do you have some code we can look at and give you some advice or do you want a finished solution?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use vector subscripts where the subscripts come from the condition.

To get the indices of the rows and columns to be retained:

```
integer, allocatable :: idx(:)
idx = PACK([(i, i=1,N)], maskmat.eq.0)
```

and then for the matrix with bits removed

```
integer, allocatable :: submat(:,:)
submat = mat(idx, idx)
```